# SQL-query for latest date in data base

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

Can You help me construct sql query which pulls out of database the entries which have the latest date.

I tried but come to deadend

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t,Table t2
WHERE t.date>t2.date
```

I think i have to use some temporary tables...it is a bit dificult for me

Comment: use max(date) , or limit 1 order by date desc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrieve rows ordered by date, descending:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC
```

Retrieve the 5 rows with the most recent dates:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select * from Table where date_column = (select max(date_column) from Table)
```